# Django Tutorial Help - "Not Found: /polls/index.html"

Tags: python, html, django

Working through the Django tutorial and have run into a problem I cannot figure out. Help would be appreciated. What am I missing here? Run this the tutorial a couple times now double checking all work, and code seems to match.

Error: "Not Found: /polls/index.html"

**mysite/urls.py:**

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),

]
```

**polls/templates/polls/index.html**:

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

**polls/urls.py**:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.detail, name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/results/$', views.results, name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9]+)/vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

**polls/views.py**:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import Question


def index(request):
    latest_question_list = Question.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
    template = loader.get_template('polls/index.html')
    context = {
        'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
    }
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world. You're at the polls index.")

def detail(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're looking at question %s." % question_id)

def results(request, question_id):
    response = "You're looking at the results of question %s."
    return HttpResponse(response % question_id)

def vote(request, question_id):
    return HttpResponse("You're voting on question %s." % question_id)
```

Comment: Is `"polls.apps"` in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @pycoder, yes: 
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'polls.apps.PollsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

Comment: Or is 'polls.apps' seperate from 'polls.apps.PollsConfig' ?

Comment: Yeah, it should just be `polls.apps`, not `polls.apps.PollsConfig`.

Comment: I'm not getting and error... any idea what is it?     Also why changed it to that? Django tutorial for 1.11 clearly shows polls.apps.pollsconfig? : RuntimeError: Model class polls.models.Question doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.

Comment: Is /polls/index.html the URL that you are putting into your browser? If so, why?

Comment: Figured it out... Just learning :) don't need to reference /poll/index.html in my url. Got it working. thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

[image: be care about the structure]

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial03/)

> Template namespacing
>
> Now we might be able to get away with putting our templates directly
>   in polls/templates (rather than creating another polls subdirectory),
>   but it would actually be a bad idea. Django will choose the first
>   template it finds whose name matches, and if you had a template with
>   the same name in a different application, Django would be unable to
>   distinguish between them. We need to be able to point Django at the
>   right one, and the easiest way to ensure this is by namespacing them.
>   That is, by putting those templates inside another directory named for
>   the application itself.

And in setting.py,
replace with this part:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

Comment: If you are quoting from documentation, you need to mention the source

Answer (score 0):

just add polls.apps in settings.py

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls.apps'
]
```

now you can add your template at `polls/templates/polls/index.html`
and calling from polls via `loader.get_template('polls/index.html')` or

```py
render(request, 'polls/index.html',
                  {'latest_question_list': latest_question_list,
                   })
```